# Change size on images systematically in PHP

Tags: php, image

In my website I have a directory called /images and I have already filled it with 300 images, but I discovered that there was something wrong. All the images that wasn't perfect squares 1:1 were stretched and very bad looking. If I make some PHP code that will fix that problem how do I automatically get all the images to run through the script, systematically?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered a loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(glob("images/*.jpg") as $image) {
    // Do whatever you need to do with the picture
}
```

[glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) can help finding filenames using a pattern and returns an array